# if total hours count is 00:00 then how i get or convert to 00:01

Tags: python-2.7, sql-server-2008, pyodbc

I am able to get total hours but I wanted if count is 00:00 output should be 00:01

This is my query.

```
CONVERT(varchar(3),DATEDIFF(minute,MIN(clock), MAX (clock))/60) + ':' + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(varchar(2),DATEDIFF(minute,MIN (clock),MAX (clock))%'60'),2) as TotalHours
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query using case :

```
SELECT 
CASE CONVERT(varchar(3),DATEDIFF(minute,MIN(clock), MAX (clock))/60) + ':' + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(varchar(2),DATEDIFF(minute,MIN (clock),MAX (clock))%'60'),2) 
WHEN '0:00' THEN '00:01'
ELSE CONVERT(varchar(3),DATEDIFF(minute,MIN(clock), MAX (clock))/60) + ':' + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(varchar(2),DATEDIFF(minute,MIN (clock),MAX (clock))%'60'),2) 
END
as TotalHours
```